# Уточняющий оборот или нет?

Tags: запятые

"Там, на столе" - это уточняющий оборот? Слово, которое уточняется и слово, уточняющее его, должны являться теми же членами предложения, но что-то мне подсказывает, что "на столе" - это не наречие, ведь можно вставить слово. "На этом столе", "на деревянном столе". Тогда, получается, не надо ставить запятую и этот оборот не является уточняющим? Мне кажется, что надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так наречие - это же не член предложения, а часть речи. Его не нужно искать.

`На столе` - это уточняющий оборот, выраженный обстоятельством (вопрос - где?).

Хотя в разговорной речи часто вообще не делают паузу после `там`.

В гугл-книгах в начале предложения данная фраза часто без запятой. Видимо связано с разговорным стилем. Иногда и в конце:

`И потом, Алексей вдруг понял, что это за железки масляно блестят там на столе.`

Если хочется сделать уточнение - нужна запятая.

`Именно там, на столе, где он и оставил ее вечером, надрывалась, исходила в пронзительном звоне вчерашняя находка.`

Если фраза цельная (где оно? - `там на столе`) - без запятой. Но это ближе к разговорному стилю.